# How does buying more of a foreign currency devalue a nation's currency?

Tags: interest-rate

If a country wants to devalue their countries, why does buying more of a foreign countries currency devalue their currency?

I was reading the top answer from this question [How does a country devalue its currency?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6875/how-does-a-country-devalue-its-currency) and it states that buying more of a foreign currency will increase the supply of the yuan. Why and how is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because buying country A's currency priced in country B's currency means selling country B's currency.

*Simplified but not simplistic example*: say that you have 80¥ and want to buy 10€. When buying/demanding these 10€, you will actually simultaneoualy also sell 80¥ i.e. by doing so you become a supplier of (€-priced) yuans. And because selling an asset generally exerts a downward pressure on its price, the price of 1¥ expressed in euros will decrease. Hence the explanation you read.

Comment: Any question @ChristopherU ?

Comment: Could you just quickly explain the last part (And because selling an asset generally exerts a downward pressure on its price, the price of 1¥ expressed in euros will decrease), I don't really get that? Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherU : 1) If I have 1¥ and that I want to sell it, I have "to find someone" who wants to buy it. It is very likely that I will find someone who will tell me : *"I can buy it from you, but sell it cheaper (in euro), otherwise I'll buy it elsewhere"*. Given that I may not be the only seller on the market, I will accept the transaction price and sell it cheaper than I first expected.  2) By using the word *"generally"*, I mean that I may have found someone who is okay to buy it at the current price without negocation, which will not lead to a decrease in price, not very common though.

Answer (score 0):

In easy words it will increase the supply of the currency in the international market and thus devaluation will happen because demand will be same.
International market is a free trade economy where currencies value change because of the forces of supply and demand